# CurrentAppSimulator.LicenseInformation getting exception "A quota was exceeded" in windows store app

Tags: windows-8, licensing, windows-store-apps

In my Windows Store App the following exception is thrown when I attempt to access
    `CurrentAppSimulator.LicenseInformation`

*"A quota was exceeded. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x803D0008)"*

I have tried creating a new solution and copying all the code files across to it but still get the same error, I have found no help on MSDN or Googling in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little help from Googling I have discovered that uninstalling the app from the windows start screen seems to help.

When you debug your application seems to get installed and appears on the start screen, in the past I had just ignored this fact. After uninstalling the application and debugging again I was able to get past that error and was able to see the real underlying errors that were occurring. I'm not sure of the relationship between these underlying errors and the one we are discussing here, I suspect they are not directly related.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wwsapi/thread/765a4e93-e2c0-4a24-82c1-f86384493c14) and another one [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wwsapi/thread/800c61f6-0e14-4a1c-bb8d-0e14761ddcdb), I would say you are exceeding a memory limit somewhere.  The linked questions/answers indicate that "A quota was exceeded" indicates you used up your entire heap or that your message buffer isn't large enough.

Additionally, some users have indicated that they get that error when their developer license has expired and have had to re-install Windows 8 to resolve the issue.

Comment: The developer license expires every month and needs to be renewed, when I renew it, it only gives me a new license for a further month. The license did expire at about the time this started to happen I think but it has been renewed since. I don't think re-installing windows would be a good solution as I would have to do it every month.